# MySQL Workbench: "Operation has completed with warnings"

Tags: mysql-workbench, warning

As I synchronize my database, MySQL Workbench reports:

> "*Operation has completed with warning. Please see logs for details.*"

But the Message Log just says:

```
Fetching schema list.
OK
WARNING: Server configuration check
```

I don't know what this is supposed to mean. Is the Workbench warning me about some dubious relations I implemented in my database or is something wrong with my server? What does it want from me?

Btw: The generated script runs without errors. The database gets generated and migrated to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is a bit unconcrete, so here's a translation: it appears when the statement 'SELECT @@lower_case_table_names' returns -1 or 0 (only for Win and OS X). So check, if case sensitivity is an issue for you.

**Update:**

The message you see is in fact only the title for a (potential) error dialog. The actual message is not listed in that small log. Look in the WB log (Help -> Show Log File) for the details.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think this might be the problem. I have changed `lower_case_table_names` in the config file to 0 and now I see in the documentation: "*You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or OS X).*" I'm going to check this after work and check your answer if changing that solved the problem. :)